# Characterization of solutions of a differential inequality.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inequality

While estimating the solution of some PDE, I needed assumptions on some positive coefficient function $g \in \text{C}^2([0,A])$ ($A>0$ is prescribed), namely, that there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that
$$
0\leq g'\leq (2-\varepsilon) C g
$$
holds where $C>0$ is some also prescribed constant.
I am aware that using Grönwall this implies estimates on $g$.

I am interested (if it exists) in a "nicer" description of those functions in $\text{C}^2([0,A])$ satisfying the above inequality.